# Keeping errors from appearing to the user in node.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling, coffeescript, express

How would I keep uncaught errors from being sent to the users when I use `express.js` in `node.js`?

Let's say that I have the following route set up:

```
app.get "/err", (req, res) ->
  throw new Error "Something went wrong"
  res.send "Hello World", 200
```

And to handle my exceptions:

```
process.on "uncaughtException", (err) ->
  console.log "OH NOES: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION"
  console.log err.message, err.stack
  process.exit(1) #Exit with error
```

Still, when I visit the `/err` in my browser, `Error: Something went wrong` is shown along with a stack trace of the error. The same thing occurs if  I put all my routes inside a `try/catch`-block.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this page for how to suppress the error output:

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling

Comment: That did it. I had to put the error handling block after my routes though, which was kind of unexpected.